# How to pass a reference between two unrelated ViewControllers for a main and an external window (No segue, different SceneDelegates)

Tags: ios, swift

**Question:** What is the most “Swiftian” way of passing a reference between two unrelated ViewControllers (*e.g.,* two ViewControllers that are independently instantiated at different times)?

I am writing an iOS app that will have two windows: one on the device and one optional window that is external (*e.g.,* AirPlayed to a TV or projector). Each window has its own SceneDelegate and ViewController. The external window is set up when the user starts AirPlay or at start-up if AirPlay is already running. Both setups are managed “automatically” through storyboards and the plist.

The challenge is that both windows need to display the same live camera feed. In my current implementation, the main ViewController updates both its own view and the view controlled by the external View Controller.

I think the main ViewController should be the delegate of the external ViewController, but I can't figure out how to pass the necessary reference between the two ViewControllers. This would typically be done during a segue, but there is no segue for an external view.

My current solution works, but is old fashioned. In the AppDelegate, I define a global reference to the UIImageView in the external window, if it exists:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var extImageView: UIImageView!
```

The ViewController for the external window keeps this reference up to date as needed:

```
class ExtViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var extImageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.extImageView = extImageView
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.extImageView = nil
    }

}
```

I then implement AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate in the main ViewController to update the external window:

```
// MARK: - AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate
extension CameraViewController: AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
    func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {

        let imageBuffer: CVPixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)!
        let ciimage : CIImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: imageBuffer)
        let image : UIImage = self.convert(cmage: ciimage)

        DispatchQueue.main.sync(execute: {() -> Void in
            let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
            if let imageView = appDelegate.extImageView {imageView.image = image}
        })

    }

    // Convert CIImage to CGImage
    func convert(cmage:CIImage) -> UIImage
    {
        let context:CIContext = CIContext.init(options: nil)
        let cgImage:CGImage = context.createCGImage(cmage, from: cmage.extent)!
        let image:UIImage = UIImage.init(cgImage: cgImage, scale: 1.0, orientation: extOrientation)
        return image
    }
}
```

This works, but at the cost of a global reference and a very specific, poorly reusable bit of code. Is there a more elegant, reusable approach, perhaps using a delegate?

Comment: Don't attach them to each other. Make a new thing that has the thing they want to share and pass it to both of them (a Model, in MVC). Each talks to it and each subscribes to changes from it.  The VC's don't have any knowledge of each other

Comment: See this -- I tried to give you a place to start: https://dev.to/loufranco/ios-stackoverflow-deep-dive-how-to-get-two-vc-s-to-talk-to-each-other-528d

Comment: Check my Answer below, It will help.

Answer (score 2):

The straight forward solution for this to achieve the separation of concern is the observer pattern, check the following re-writing of your code using post notifications technique to achieve this:

```
class ExtViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var extImageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.observeImageCaptureNotification()
    }

    func deint() {
        self.removeAllObservers()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.extImageView = extImageView
    }

    func observeImageCaptureNotification() {

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(newImageDidCapture(notification:)), name: "NewImageDidCapture", object: nil)

    }

    func removeAllObservers() {

        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)

    }

    @objc private func newImageDidCapture(notification: Notification) {

        if let newImage = notification.userInfo?["image"] as? UIImage {

            self.extImageView.image = newImage

        }

    }
}


// MARK: - AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate
extension CameraViewController: AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
    func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {

        let imageBuffer: CVPixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)!
        let ciimage : CIImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: imageBuffer)
        let image : UIImage = self.convert(cmage: ciimage)

        DispatchQueue.main.sync(execute: {() -> Void in
           NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "NewImageDidCapture"), object: nil, userInfo: ["image": image])
        })

    }

    // Convert CIImage to CGImage
    func convert(cmage:CIImage) -> UIImage
    {
        let context:CIContext = CIContext.init(options: nil)
        let cgImage:CGImage = context.createCGImage(cmage, from: cmage.extent)!
        let image:UIImage = UIImage.init(cgImage: cgImage, scale: 1.0, orientation: extOrientation)
        return image
    }
}
```

Comment: My concern with this approach is that I would need to send out notifications at video frame rates. One possibility that capitalizes on your idea — but with many fewer notifications — would be to post a notification containing the reference to UIImageView every time it changes. The KVO approach mentioned by Lou Franco (above) would accomplish the same thing.